# Retag suggestion: [old] -> [old-computer] && [old-hardware]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[old](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old) (34) seeems to be a mixture of questions about old computers and old hardware, which should be retagged to [old-computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-computer) <strike>and [old-hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-hardware) respectively.</strike>*

Since there are other tags which are more descriptive, I suggest we retag the questions tagged [old](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old) and burninate it.

Also, [retro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retro), [vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage), and [legacy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/legacy) are a mixture of questions about old software and old hardware
(Thanks @DanielBeck)

`*` I have since changed my opinion to having [old-hardware] be retagged into [old-computer] as well, instead of having 2 tags which would end up being very similar

Comment: When does `[old]` become `[retro]` or `[vintage]`? It seems some additional cleaning up might be useful here...

Comment: @DanielBeck Good catch! I didn't notice those tags

Comment: Isn't an [tag:old-computer] just a collection of [tag:old-hardware] ?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver I don't think of it that way at all

Comment: @SimonSheehan if you have a better idea for what to do, please post it. I like to see alternate opinions

Comment: There's also `[legacy]`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[old](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old), [legacy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/legacy) & [vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage) were wiped. [retro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retro) & [old-computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-computer) were merged into [old-hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-hardware)